# Upload file from the specific directory (authomatically) [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created some simple tool where you can upload .csv file and display output on the website.
To do it you have press 'Browse', select file, and then press button 'Generate' and it will display output from .csv file (you can delete/edit each record).

My question is it possible to avoid selecting file manually?
I want to have only button 'Generate', after pressing it will automatically upload file and display. Of course file will be stored in some directory (directory and file name once defined won't be changed, only info in .csv could be different).

Any idea?

Comment: Are you asking if you can make the browser choose a file and upload it without the user specifying it? That might not be a very secure feature for browsers to give you.  If you need to do this regularly, using a file which will be in a predefined location, maybe write a script to do it?

Comment: I am asking from RoR point of view. Is it possible to do it? File will be uploaded to directory using scripts but I want to display what this file contain. That's why I don't want to manually select this file.

Comment: Rails can only operate on files that are in it's own local file system.  Rails can't grab files from a remote user's computer.  The actions you are talking about (selecting a file to upload) happen in the client, not the server, so Rails has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Also, if you explain a bit more about what this is being used for, someone might suggest a nicer way of achieving the end result.

Comment: There is a script which checks the stock prices and save data to .csv file (this file could be located locally). Then someone can log in to the website, press 'Generate' (in the background script will run) and get the latest status. This person has only permission to this website.

Comment: Maybe I have to assign file name to variable and read it contents

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to read from file instead of browsing, in index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag import_reports_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= File.open("public/uploadfile/a_ruby_csv.csv") {|f| f.read} %>   
<%= submit_tag "Generate report" %>
```

Before that I have:

```
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Generate report" %
```

How can I connect it with file.path ( ':file' )? 
after I use open/read I have error - syntax error, unexpected ':'